# Python xlrd- Unicode error

Tags: python, django, excel, unicode, xlrd

I'm reading my data from the excel file and then writing it into the DB in Django. I'm using python xlrd module

I'm getting the following error:-

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc1' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried all the solutions like

1) I was using `str(variable)` . Removed it. Now storing the value as it is in the DB.

2) Tried `wb = open_workbook('static/'+filename, encoding_override="utf_16_le")`

3) `.encode(error=replace)`

But nothing worked. How am I supposed to write-off this error?

**Here is my code**

```
def __init__(self, arm_id, dsp_name, DSP, hubcode, Pincode, pptl,state):
        self.arm_id = arm_id
        self.dsp_name = dsp_name
        self.DSP = DSP.zfill(2)
        self.hubcode = hubcode
        self.Pincode = Pincode
        self.pptl = pptl
        self.state = state
wb = open_workbook('static/'+filename, encoding_override="utf_16_le")
for sheet in wb.sheets():
    number_of_rows = sheet.nrows
    number_of_columns = sheet.ncols

    items = []
    arm_list = []
    pptl_list = []
    pptlcode_list = []
    count = 1
    status = 0
    for row in range(1, number_of_rows):
        values = []
        for col in range(number_of_columns):
            value  = (sheet.cell(row,col).value)
            try: value = str(int(value))
            except ValueError: pass
            finally: values.append(value)

        item = Excel(*values)
        count +=1

        arm_id = item.arm_id
        if arm_id not in arm_list:
            description = 'Arm'+arm_id
            arm_obj = Arm(arm_id = arm_id, description = description)
            arm_obj.save()
            arm_list.append(arm_id)

        pptl_id = (item.pptl)
        if pptl_id not in pptl_list: 
            try : 
                pptl_obj = PPTLconfig.objects.get(pptl_id = pptl_id)
                pptl_obj.arm_id = arm_obj
                pptl_obj.hubcode = hubcode
            except : 
                description = 'PPTL'+pptl_id
                pptl_obj = PPTLconfig(pptl_id = pptl_id, description = description , arm_id = arm_obj, hubcode = (item.hubcode))
            finally : 
                pptl_obj.save()
                pptl_list.append(pptl_id)


        code = []

        for factors in SORTATION_FACTORS:
            if factors == 'DSP': code.append((item.DSP))
            elif factors == 'Pincode': code.append((item.Pincode))
            elif factors == 'DG': code.append((item.state).zfill(4))

        code = ','.join(code)

        if code not in pptlcode_list : 
            try : 
                code_obj = PPTLcode.objects.get(code = code)
                code_obj.pconf_id = pptl_obj
            except : code_obj = PPTLcode(code=code, pconf_id=pptl_obj)
            finally : 
                code_obj.save()
                pptlcode_list.append(code)

        else : 
            error = "Duplicate PPTLcode " + code + " at Row " + str(count)
            status = 1
            delete_data(1)
            return (status,error)

###############Add ArmPrinterMapping ######################


arm_obj_list = Arm.objects.all()

for arm_obj in arm_obj_list:
    printer_name = 'Arm'+str(arm_obj.arm_id)
    ap_mapping = ArmPrinterMapping(arm_id = arm_obj, printer_name = printer_name)
    ap_mapping.save()

return (0,0)
```

Comment: Is a long program, in what line are you getting the error?

Comment: I myself dont know. :(

Comment: Post the exception's full traceback. It is there :)

Comment: Check your database encoding. xlrd returns unicode strings by default, not sure about Django ORM.

Comment: @PauloBu- I'm printing the exception like this `except,Exception e : print e` and this exception is all I get. Is there any other way of printng the exception as well?

Comment: @user1162512 Just let the exception raise and dump its contents here on the question.

Comment: @PauloBu- How do I raise it? should I write `raise Exception` ?

Comment: @user1162512: either remove `try: ... except ..` or put a single word `raise` inside `except` block

Comment: remove unnecessary code from the question or better yet: create a [minimal complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

set default encoding to `utf8`, it should work then

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```